# $(g(Y)+Z)|Y=y \sim g(y)+Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm self learning probability and I have a trouble with the following problem: let $Y,Z$ be continuous independent real random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be $C^1$. Find the distribution of $X|Y=y$, where $X=g(Y)+Z$.

**Context**: I'm particularly interested in the case where $Z$ is some gaussian noise, this kind of model is useful in robotic probabilistic state estimation.

**Guess**: $X|Y=y \sim Z+g(y)$, but how can I prove this?

**My try**: one should

1. Prove $X$ is a continuous random vector, i.e., it admits a continuous density
2. Supposing point 1, we know that the density of $X|Y=y$ can be expressed as $f_{X|Y=y}(x)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y)$. So I should compute $\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in C)=\mathbb{P}((g(Y)+Z,Y)\in C)$. Now I would like to invert $(Y,Z) \mapsto (g(Y)+Z,Y)$, but in general I cannot do this. Does it mean that I canno go on to do this?

Can you please help me out/point me to some reference material?

Comment: May be false if $Y$ and $Z$ are not assumed to be independent. Ex: $g(x)=x, Y=-Z$ Then $X=0$.

Comment: Let's suppose this, I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this just $f_{X|Y=y}(x) = f_{Z}(x-g(y))$?

Comment: @Kartik Can you please provide a proof for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of "continuous random variable" isn't the usual one, which merely requires the cumulative distribution function of the random variable to be continuous, not that it have a density.  The latter requires the cumulative distribution function to be [*absolutely continuous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), which is a stronger condition.

If $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are arbitrary random variables, then the distribution $\ P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)\ $ of $\ X\ $ given $\ Y=y\ $ is defined to be the function of $\ y\ $ which satisfies the equation
$$
P\big(X\in A,Y\in B\big)=\int_B P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)\,dF_Y(y)
$$
for all measurable $\ B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\ $.  This defines $\ P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)\ $ uniquely for all $\ y\ $ in the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory) of $\ F_Y\ $.  If $\ F_Y\ $ has a density $\ f_Y\ $, this equation reduces to
$$
P\big(X\in A,Y\in B\big)=\int_B P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)f_Y(y)\,dy\ ,
$$
but it is not necessary to assume this.

If $\ Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are independent, and $\ X=Z+g(Y)\ $ then
\begin{align}
P\big(X\in A,Y\in B\big)&=P\big(Z+g(Y)\in A, Y\in B\big)\\
&=\int_B\int_{\{z\,|\,z+g(y)\in A\}}\,dF_Z(z)\,dF_Y(y)\\
&= \int_BP\big(Z+g(y)\in A\big)\,dF_Y(y)\ .
\end{align}
Comparing this with the definitional equation of $\ P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)\ $ above, we see that
$$
P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)= P\big(Z+g(y)\in A\big)
$$
for all $\ y\ $ in the support of $\ F_Y\ $. If $\ F_Z\ $ has a density $\ f_ Z\ $ then
\begin{align}
P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)&=\int_{\{z\,|\,z+g(y)\in A\}}f_Z(z)dz\\
&=\int_Af_Z(x-g(y))\,dx\ ,
\end{align}
so in this case the conditional distribution $\ P\big(X\in A\,\big|\,Y=y\big)\ $ has the density $\ f_Z(x-g(y))\ $.

Comment: Thank you very much. One quick clarification: how did you use independence?

Comment: $$
P\big(Z+g(Y)\in A, Y\in B\big)\\
=\int_B\int_{\{z\,|\,z+g(y)\in A\}}\,dF_Z(z)\,dF_Y(y)\ .
$$ Without independence this would have to be$$
P\big(Z+g(Y)\in A, Y\in B\big)\\
=\int_B\int_{\{z\,|\,z+g(y)\in A\}}\,dF_{Z,Y}(z,y)\ .
$$